# Unable to import 'selenium' pylint(import-error) (solution)

Tags: python, selenium, pylint

I had this error while I was working on my assignment using `python 3.7` in `Visual Studio Code`. I tried to comment in some previous stackoverflow posts but it doesn't allow me to comment. So I'm sharing the solution I found in this post.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!!! Let me tell you I love your username ^^ Please may you edit your post, if you write in a Q&A style you may first write the problem in a post, then post your solution in response to this post. Thanks a lot for sharing :) See you soon

Comment: @Y-BCause thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a solution I came up with the following, using also steps from [this](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_linting/) link.

1. **Create virtual environment (venv) in the same folder your python file is located**
   C:\YourFolderPathHere>python3 -m venv nameOfYourVenv
2. **Activate your python virtual environment**
   C:\YourFolderPathHere>nameOfYourVenv\Scripts\activate.bat
3. **Make sure selenium and pylint are installed within this virtual environment**
   (nameOfYourVenv) C:\YourFolderPathHere>pip install selenium
   (nameOfYourVenv) C:\YourFolderPathHere>pip install pylint
4. **Launch VS Code from cmd**
   (nameOfYourVenv) C:\YourFolderPathHere>code .

Other solutions weren't helpful for me but this worked so I hope it'll be useful for you as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a bit different. My vscode's interpreter was pointing to another version of python.
To change the python3 interpreter, open command palette(ctrl+shift+p) and search for, *Python : Select Interpreter*. Now change that to the correct path and it is good to go.